# SVG icons aren't showing after some duration of time in React?

Tags: reactjs, svg, frontend

SVG images aren't showing after a very short time in react. Below I have put that xmlns code

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="145.03" height="84.204" viewBox="0 0 145.03 84.204">
 <g id="noun_Arrow_2601665" transform="translate(-193.719 -290.21)">
  <g id="Group_236" data-name="Group 236" transform="translate(193.719 290.21)">
    <path id="Path_213" data-name="Path 213" d="M208.971,292.671l57.18,58.444,57.5-58.444c7.582- 
    7.9,20.534,5.055,12.636,12.952l-64.762,66.658a7.054,7.054,0,0,1-10.109,0l-65.394- 
    66.658C188.437,297.726,201.389,284.773,208.971,292.671Z" transform="translate(-193.719 -290.21)" 
    fill="#fff" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
  </g>
 </g>
```

This is how I imported and used this SVGs

```
import downArrowIcon from '../../../../../assets/icons/left-ar.svg';
<img src={downArrowIcon} alt="DropDownArrow" />
```